# I have touble when including files with makefile for a stm32f4xx

Tags: gnu-make, stm32f4discovery, stm32f4, makefile, arm-none-eabi-gcc

I'am starting using Linux and I have some trouble using some stm32f4 libraries for my project *gcc-testing*.
All the CMSIS programs needed are inside the STM32F4_Discovery_FW_V1.1.0 and the project is arranged like this:

```
~
|__
|  |
|   STM32F4XX
|    |
src   STM32F4_Discovery_FW_V1.1.0
  |
  ggc-testing
    |
    makefile
    main.c
    stm32f4xx_config.h
    stm32_flash.ld
    system_stm32f4xx.c
```

The main.c and the system_stm32f4xx.c use the stm32f4xx.h file that is inside the STM32F4_Discovery_FW_V1.1.0/Libraries/CMSIS/ST/STM32F4xx/Include
The error I get from the terminal is:

[Make file console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9dBI.png)

My make file:

```
PROJ_NAME=main

STM_DIR=~/STM32F4XX/STM32F4-Discovery_FW_V1.1.0
STM_SRC = $(STM_DIR)/Libraries/STM32F4xx_StdPeriph_Driver/src

vpath %.c $(STM_SRC)

SRCS   = main.c
SRCS  += system_stm32f4xx.c
SRCS += $(STM_DIR)/Libraries/CMSIS/ST/STM32F4xx/Source/Templates/TrueSTUDIO/startup_stm32f4xx.s

INC_DIRS  = $(STM_DIR)/Utilities/STM32F4-Discovery
INC_DIRS += $(STM_DIR)/Libraries/CMSIS/Include
INC_DIRS += $(STM_DIR)/Libraries/CMSIS/ST/STM32F4xx/Include
INC_DIRS += $(STM_DIR)/Libraries/STM32F4xx_StdPeriph_Driver/inc
INC_DIRS += .

TOOLS_DIR = /opt/gcc-arm-embedded/gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_7-2013q1/bin

CC      = arm-none-eabi-gcc
OBJCOPY = arm-none-eabi-objcopy
GDB     = arm-none-eabi-gdb

INCLUDE = $(addprefix -I,$(INC_DIRS))
DEFS    = -DUSE_STDPERIPH_DRIVER

CFLAGS  = -ggdb
CFLAGS += -O0 
CFLAGS += -Wall -Wextra -Warray-bounds
CFLAGS += -mlittle-endian -mthumb -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb-interwork
CFLAGS += -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16

LFLAGS  = -Tstm32_flash.ld

.PHONY: $(PROJ_NAME)
$(PROJ_NAME): $(PROJ_NAME).elf

$(PROJ_NAME).elf: $(SRCS)
    $(CC) $(INCLUDE) $(DEFS) $(CFLAGS) $(LFLAGS) $^ -o $@ 
    $(OBJCOPY) -O ihex $(PROJ_NAME).elf   $(PROJ_NAME).hex
    $(OBJCOPY) -O binary $(PROJ_NAME).elf $(PROJ_NAME).bin

clean:
    rm -f *.o $(PROJ_NAME).elf $(PROJ_NAME).hex $(PROJ_NAME).bin

# Flash the STM32F4
flash: 
    st-flash write $(PROJ_NAME).bin 0x8000000

.PHONY: debug
debug:
# before you start gdb, you must start st-util
    $(GDB) $(PROJ_NAME).elf
```

Hope enyne can help with this.

Answer (score 0):

After gnu `make` generates a cmd-line (eg `gcc`), use of a `~` would rely on `make` executing a shell and the shell expanding an arg with a leading unquoted `~`.  Based on your line with `$(addprefix`, try adding a space between `-I` and `,$(INC_DIRS)`

However, the overhead from executing a shell can be undesirable and the extra exec is often easy to avoid; for this case, replace `~` with  `$(HOME)`

Example `Makefile` :

```
SUBDIR := some/incdir
TILDE_SUBDIR := ~/$(SUBDIR)

NOT_DELIM := $(addprefix -I,$(TILDE_SUBDIR))
DELIM_INC := $(addprefix -I ,$(TILDE_SUBDIR))
HOME_SUBDIR := $(HOME)/$(SUBDIR)

PHONY: all

all:
    @echo NOT_DELIM $(NOT_DELIM)
    @echo DELIM_INC $(DELIM_INC)
    @echo HOME_SUBDIR $(HOME_SUBDIR)
```

Output :

```
NOT_DELIM -I~/some/incdir
DELIM_INC -I /home/user1/some/incdir
HOME_SUBDIR /home/user1/some/incdir
```

Comment: Thanks, I was missing a space `INCLUDE = $(addprefix -I ,$(INC_DIRS))`.
Also after that I had another error:
`__libc_init_array.c` : ../init.c :40: undefined reference to `init`
I solved it by adding an  'void _init(void){return ;}' at the top of the main.c file but I am not realy sure if I should be adding it there.

Comment: Without seeing the sources, I'd guess `_init()` should be defined somewhere, possibly a missing obj file when linking, `#ifdef` condition not met, maybe a missing `__attribute__((weak))`